# rsync does not exit and stuck when an error happens

Tags: ssh, command-line, rsync

I'm sending a big file to a remote server with rsync through SSH. I have a problem, it gets interrupted very often. So I wanted to let the rsync problem auto retry when that fails.

I read this [linux - Resume rsync over SSH after broken connection? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/302842/resume-rsync-over-ssh-after-broken-connection)
and I'm trying something like this:

```
while ( ! rsync -avz --append --partial -h --info=progress2  -e 'ssh -p 6001' -r src user@host:'dist' ); do sleep 5; done
```

But this does not work properly, since the rsync script does not exit but something prevents its exiting.

```
Connection to [host] closed by remote host.
```

So I need to quit the program manually typing ctrl-C and rerun the rsync script manually...

```
^C^Crsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at rsync.c(644) [sender=3.1.2]
```

So, what's the problem here?

Comment: Are you sure rsync does not throw any other error, like setting permissions or so? If filesystem have any problem at all it will return non-zero status. You also do not need -r with -a. The reason of script hanging can be tied to terminal problems as well. How do you run the script with while?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in above, that's all. okay, I'll try without -r. I run the command on a normal environment, it's WSL Ubuntu 18.04 bash on Tmux, particularly. Tmux can be the issue?

Comment: Try running rsync -avz --append --partial -h --info=progress2  -e 'ssh -p 6001' -r src user@host:'dist' ; echo $? and see if it really return zero status on success.

Comment: I mean the command stuck without exiting. So I don't think I can see any return value 0 or else unless I do ctrl-C manually. Also I tried the command without "while" but it's the same, stucking after an error.

Comment: Are you sharing the connection with a second session? Take a look at your ssh config.

Comment: If not a "while" problem rsync is known to hang on large transfers in bad network. Try it with --timeout=600 and --block-size=1048576. Bad net is also a problem for ssh, use these options:
KeepAlive yes
ServerAliveInterval 30
ServerAliveCountMax 6